# Method does not exist or incorrect signature error

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

When running the following code I get this error message:

> [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddressof(List)

```
public class outboundemail1 {
    public void sendMail(){
        String[] toadd = new String[]{'test@gmail.com'};
        String[] toCc = new String[]{'test@asia.com'};
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddress(toadd);
        email.setCcAddresses(tocc);
        email.setSubject('Hi from salesforce sender bhavani');
        email.setPlainTextBody('Welcome to Salesforce Email for the first time');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email2=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email2.setToAddress(toadd);
        email2.setSubject('HTML Body');
        email2.setHTMLBody('<h1style="colour:green">Welcome to Salesforce Email for the first time</h1>');
        email2.setSenderDisplayName('bhavani818584884');
        Messaging.Email[] emails = new Messaging.Email[] {email,email2};
        Messaging.SendEmail(emails);
    }
}
```

This is the code of my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page OutboundEmail1 ot=new OutboundEmail1> ot.sendMais(); </apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about the error? What's the name of the method which doesn't exist? And provide us your visualforce page.

Comment: this is the error shows as[Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddressof(List)

Comment: <apex:page OutboundEmail1 ot=new OutboundEmail1>
ot.sendMais();
</apex:page>             this is my visualforcepage

Comment: martin lezer did u got my problem?thnq for ur quick responds

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) about the SingleEmailMessage class, there is no `setToAddress` method. Its name is: `setToAddresses`.

Answer (score 0):

In your method you've wrote:

```
email.setToAddress(toadd);
```

There's a slight typo in that the method you want is:

```
email.setToAddresses(toadd);
```

Note the extra "*es*" in the method name.

Comment: yeah got it,Thank you Martin Lezer for giving solution to my problem,i am done with that thnk u soo much :-)